# Rename {writelatex} to {overleaf}, keep {writelatex} as a synonym for {overleaf}

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

[writelatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writelatex) has been renamed to [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/about).

I suggest to rename the [writelatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writelatex) tag to [overleaf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overleaf) and make [writelatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writelatex) a synonym for [overleaf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overleaf).

Comment: I think in this case it would be sufficient to create the [tag:overleaf] tag, and then vote on [tag:writelatex] as being a synonym for [tag:overleaf]. Once this is established, all [tag:writelatex] will change to [tag:overleaf] on already-tagged posts. I think that's how it works...

Comment: @Werner Or we ping a mod to do that :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Agreed and implemented: see [overleaf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overleaf) :-)

Comment: Did we loose the tag wiki or was it empty before?